# Meaning of “février sevré”?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

I recently saw this in a Facebook post (Québec):

> Le février sevré se termine bientôt!

Is "*weaned February*" an idiom, or is there some other meaning for "*sevré*" that I haven't been able to find?

Comment: Was the context related to alcohol, tobacco, meat?

Comment: May e something close to a "dry january" campaign ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally asked the author, who replied: “*mois de février sans alcool, sevrage*”.

It's a local name for the [Go Dry this February - Dry Feb](https://www.dryfeb.ca/) fund raising campaign (plus it reduces alcohol consumption, one cause of cancer) by the Canadian Cancer Society each year.

[Participez à DRY FEB™ | Société canadienne du cancer](https://cancer.ca/fr/ways-to-give/dry-feb)

Comment: Well, this is one of those "you hadda be there", right?